# Wix database script execute depending on chosen features on FeatureTree

Tags: sql, wix

I my installer I want to run some scripts depending on features chosen in FeatureTree. But is seems like installer execute all script which I added.

```
 <Feature Id="FeatureProduct" Title="App Setup" Level="1" ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER">
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="ComponentsProduct" />
  <ComponentRef Id="ComponentMenuStart" />
  <ComponentRef Id="ComponentDesktopFolder"/>
  <ComponentRef Id='SqlComponent.DatabaseSchemeCreator' />
  <Feature Id='NE051' Title='Module1' Description='Module 1' Level='1'>
    <ComponentRef Id='ComponentModules.Module1' />
    <ComponentGroupRef Id='ComponentGroupModul1' />
    <ComponentRef Id='SqlComponent.DatabaseModule1' />
  </Feature>
  <Feature Id='NE041' Title='module2' Description='Module 2' Level='1'>
    <ComponentRef Id='ComponentModules.Module2' />
    <ComponentGroupRef Id='ComponentGroupModul2' />
  </Feature>
</Feature>


  <Fragment>
<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
  <Component Id="SqlComponent.DatabaseSchemeCreator" Guid="2E7CB14E-7190-4C35-A83F-9B1A5C7A2923">
    <Condition><![CDATA[AUTO_CONFIGURE_DB = 1]]></Condition>
    <sql:SqlDatabase Id='SqlComponent.DatabaseSchemeCreator' Database='[PROP_SQL_DATABASE_NAME]' Server='[PROP_SQL_SERVER_NAME]'
                    CreateOnInstall='yes' ContinueOnError='no'>
      <sql:SqlScript Id='SqlComponent.DatabaseSchemeCreator' BinaryKey='CreateTablesScript' ExecuteOnInstall='yes' />
    </sql:SqlDatabase>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

```
  <Fragment>
<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
  <Component Id="SqlComponent.DatabaseModule1" Guid="B7E392C5-3A1E-4F73-9B86-54394E93330B">
    <Condition><![CDATA[AUTO_CONFIGURE_DB = 1]]></Condition>
    <sql:SqlDatabase Id='SqlComponent.DatabaseModule1' Database='[PROP_SQL_DATABASE_NAME]' Server='[PROP_SQL_SERVER_NAME]'
                    CreateOnInstall='yes' ContinueOnError='no'>
      <sql:SqlScript Id='SqlComponent.DatabaseModule1' BinaryKey='Module1Script' ExecuteOnInstall='yes' />
    </sql:SqlDatabase>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

Every time I don't mark module 1 in FeatureTree to install Wix execute a script for module 1. Condition in components work well. Do you have any ideas how to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you didn't use any feature state for your components (or where does the `AUTO_CONFIGURE_DB`-property come from?).
If I understood you correctly you want those scripts to be executed only if the related Feature has been set to be installed. According to [Conditional Statement Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368012%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you can use the `&feature-action` in your conditions:

```
For example, the conditional expression "&MyFeature=3" evaluates to True only if MyFeature is changing from its current state to the state of being installed on the local computer, INSTALLSTATE_LOCAL.
```

In your case this would probably translate to the following, e.g. execute the script only if the feature `NE051` has been selected to be installed locally:

```
<Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
      <Component Id="SqlComponent.DatabaseSchemeCreator" Guid="2E7CB14E-7190-4C35-A83F-9B1A5C7A2923">
        <Condition><![CDATA[&NE051=3]]></Condition>
        <sql:SqlDatabase Id='SqlComponent.DatabaseSchemeCreator' Database='[PROP_SQL_DATABASE_NAME]' Server='[PROP_SQL_SERVER_NAME]' CreateOnInstall='yes' ContinueOnError='no'>
          <sql:SqlScript Id='SqlComponent.DatabaseSchemeCreator' BinaryKey='CreateTablesScript' ExecuteOnInstall='yes' />
        </sql:SqlDatabase>
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
</Fragment>
```